# propagating error from a callback in nodes

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm a newbie as far as node is concerned, so what i am asking here might be plain out stupid, so bear with me.

Below is the code for a node module that connects to a given mongodb database, my problem is on line19 where i am trying to throw the error in case the connection to the db server cannot be made or the db server is down, but node complains , please advise.

Code:-

```
var dbinit_func = function(db_name){
try{
// require mongoose , if it's not there
// throw an exception and but out
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
}
catch(err){
  throw "Error Mongoose Not Found"
}
try{
// connect to the db
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/" + db_name);
// get a reference to the connection object
var db_connection = mongoose.connection;
// subscribe to events on the connection object
db_connection.on('error', function(err){
  // holy cow "A Connection Error", shout it out loud
  // and but out
    throw new Error(err.message);--> This is where the problem Occurs
});
// bind to the connection open event , we just need to
// do it once , so we use the once method on the
// connection object
db_connection.once('open', function(){})
}
catch(err){
  // we got an error most probably a connection error
  // so we but out from here
  throw "Connection Error";
}
}

module.exports = dbinit_func;
```

Message spitted by Node:-

```
/Users/tristan625/projects/node_projs/school_web/models/db.js:19
    throw new Error(err.message);
          ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is written in a synchronous style, as seen by the try/catch blocks. What you must understand, is that the mongoose.connect function is asynchronous. When you call throw new Error(), that call will occur inside of a callback, which is outside the scope of your try/catch blocks, hence you can't handle the error using them.

Your dbinit_func must be written to allow for a callback

Here's a pretty standard way of doing what you're doing

```
function dbinit_func(db_name, callback) {
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ + db_name', { auto_reconnect: true });

  var db = mongoose.connection;
  db.once('error', function(err){

    //trigger callback with an error
    callback(err);
  });

  db.once('open', function() {

    //trigger callback with success
    callback(null, 'DB Connection is open');
  });

}

module.exports = dbinit_func;

// to call this function, you'd want to do something like this

var dbinit = require('/path/to/your/module');

dbinit('mydatabasename', function(err, res){
  // at this point, there will either be  an error
  if (err) console.log(err.message);

  // else it will be success
  console.log(res);

});
```